# Before Download Page

Tags: timer, download

I would like some help with my site. My issue is that when people download files it just downloads them instead of taking them to a page before they can download them for example like a page with a timer on it. So I would like it if someone could tell me how to let make them view a page before downloading it, Much appreciated if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can here is codding where you can find the codding for countdown timer before download link  appears : http://www.makingdifferent.com/make-countdown-timer-download-button-link-appears/

Cheers !!